# creating virtual host in WAMP

Tags: php, wamp, virtualhost

I'm using Win7 and all my asp.net applications are running at port 80

I've WAMP installed at c:\wamp and i've my php project folder under c:\wamp\www\ as proj1,proj2 etc.,

Now i tried to create virtual host with below steps

1) edited 'hosts' file and added below

```
127.0.0.1:9091    testsite1.mymachine.com
```

2) Opened the file **"httpd.conf"** at **"C:/wamp/bin/apache/Apache2.2.22/conf/"** and uncommented the line "Include conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf".

3) Opened the file **"httpd.vhosts.conf"** at **"C:/wamp/bin/apache/Apache2.2.22/conf/extra"** and added the below

```
<Directory C:/wamp/www/proj1>
Order Deny,Allow   
Allow from all 
</Directory>
```

after the above code added the below

```
<VirtualHost *:9091>   
DocumentRoot "C:/wamp/www/proj1" 
ServerName testsite1.mymachine.com
</VirtualHost>
```

4) Saved all the above edited files from step 1 through step 3, restarted the wamp server services.

But, i'm unable to access my proj1 using "testsite1.mymachine.com". did i missed anything ? Also please take note by using "http://localhost:8081/" i'm able to see wampserver - server configuration page.

Many Thanks

Comment: Did you make database entry of the URL ? Also i think you can eliminate port from host file. Check this URL: http://foundationphp.com/tutorials/apache_vhosts.php

Comment: Do you added Listen 9091

Comment: @Suraj - where to add the listen 9091

Comment: if your apache is running on port 8081, then you have to configure your `hosts` and `vhosts` file with the same port, why are you using 9091 port in them?

Comment: Listen 8865 
<VirtualHost *:8865>
   DocumentRoot "C:/wamp/www/proj1" 
ServerName testsite1.mymachine.com
</VirtualHost>

Comment: Here is a post that should explain [how to setup Virtual Hosts](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23665064/project-links-do-not-work-on-wamp-server/23990618#23990618)

Answer (score 1):

1. goto `F:\wamp\bin\apache\Apache2.2.21\conf` and open `httpd.conf` file in text editor
2. change line from `#LoadModule vhost_alias_module modules/mod_vhost_alias.so`
   to this `LoadModule vhost_alias_module modules/mod_vhost_alias.so` (uncomment)
3. find following lines

   `# Virtual hosts
    #Include conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf`

   replace it with

   `# Virtual hosts
   Include conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf`
4. now goto `F:\wamp\bin\apache\Apache2.2.21\conf\extra` and open `httpd-vhosts.conf`
   at the end add following code to `httpd-vhosts.conf`

   ```
   <VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerAdmin webmaster@dummy-host2.example.com
   DocumentRoot "C:/wamp/www/(project folder name)"
   ServerName (the name with which you want to deploy your project in the browser)
   ServerAlias (copy paste the ServerName)
   ErrorLog "logs/(deploy_name)-error.log"
   CustomLog "logs/(deploy_name)-access.log" common
     <Directory "/">
        Deny from all
        Allow from 127.0.0.1
     </Directory>
   </VirtualHost>
   ```
5. finallly update the hosts file in windows system
   goto `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc` open `hosts` using notepad (open notepad as administrator).

   find line       `127.0.0.1       localhost`

   under it write  `127.0.0.1        (copy paste the ServerName from "httpd-vhosts.conf")`
6. restart all the services from wamp.
7. this should get the virtual host running, just type the server name in the addres bar of browser and hit enter.